# Is there a keyboard shortcut to unfocus / blur active form field?

Tags: google-chrome, github, keyboard-shortcuts

When navigating through form inputs via `TAB` and `SHIFT+TAB`, is there a keyboard shortcut to un-focus the page (and blurring the active form input)?

Example:

Github has a lot of useful keyboard shortcuts, e.g. `g p` in a repository navigates to open pull requests. However, if I've clicked into a textarea I can't use website keyboard shortcuts anymore. To make keyboard shortcuts work again, I have to click (with my mouse!) outside the textarea. Is there a better way to do this in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

This was frustrating me also.. so I made a script! This works in Tampermonkey for Chrome, should also work in Greasemonkey for Firefox.

Just press Escape to de-focus the input. It's also smart enough to only unfocus input elements.

You can choose to activate it on *github* or just on all web sites.

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { // Escape is 27 on my keyboard - can be modified as needed
        var focused = document.activeElement;      
        if (focused.tagName == 'INPUT' || focused.tagName == 'TEXTAREA') {
            focused.blur();
        }
    }
};
```

Hope you're able to receive this since it's been several months.

Answer (score 3):

since `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` has been deprecated and is not recommended although some browsers may still support, here's the actual working code (which is an update to the code originally posted by **sricks** above)

```
(function () {
  window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.code === 'Escape') {
      const focused = document.activeElement;
      const elems = ['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'];
      if (elems.includes(focused.tagName)) {
        focused.blur();
      }
    }
  };
}());
```